# {up, down}speedgraphs not shown using `lua_parse lua_func`

Tags: conky

Here is my `conkyrc`:

```lua
conky.config = {
    use_xft = true, -- use xft?
    font = 'DejaVuSans:size=9', -- font name
    xftalpha = 1,
    uppercase = false, -- all text in uppercase?
    pad_percents = 0,
    text_buffer_size = 2048,
    override_utf8_locale = true, -- Force UTF8? note that UTF8 support required XFT
    use_spacer = 'none', -- Add spaces to keep things from moving about?  This only affects certain objects.

    update_interval = 1, -- Update interval in seconds
    double_buffer = true, -- Use double buffering (reduces flicker, may not work for everyone)
    total_run_times = 0, -- This is the number of times Conky will update before quitting. Set to zero to run forever.

    -- Create own window instead of using desktop (required in nautilus)
    own_window = true,
    own_window_class = 'Conky',
    own_window_transparent = true,
    own_window_argb_visual = true,
    own_window_argb_value = 255,
    own_window_type = 'desktop', -- transparency seems to work without this line
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,sticky,below,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',

    -- Minimum size of text area
    minimum_height = 50,
    minimum_width = 210,

    draw_shades = false, -- draw shades?
    draw_outline = false, -- draw outlines?
    draw_borders = false, -- draw borders around text?
    draw_graph_borders = false, -- draw borders around graphs
    stippled_borders = 0, -- stripled borders?

    imlib_cache_size = 0, -- Imlib2 image cache size, in bytes. Increase this value if you use $image lots. Set to 0 to disable the image cache.

    -- Gap between borders of screen and text. Same thing as passing -x at command line
    gap_x = 90,
    gap_y = 5,

    alignment = 'middle_right', -- alignment on {y_axis}_{x_axis}

    cpu_avg_samples = 2, -- number of cpu samples to average. set to 1 to disable averaging
    net_avg_samples = 2, -- number of net samples to average. set to 1 to disable averaging

    no_buffers = true, -- Subtract file system buffers from used memory?

    default_color = 'e0e0e0',
    default_shade_color = '000000',
    default_outline_color = '000000',

    temperature_unit = 'celsius',

    color1 = 'ff55ff', -- heading's color
    color2 = 'ffffff', -- normal text's color

    lua_load = '.conky/netdevs.lua',
};

conky.text = [[
...
${color1}NET: ${hr 2}${color2}${lua_parse conky_show_netdevs}
...
]]
```

Here is `.config/netdevs.lua`:

```lua
-- conky_show_netdevs : template for network
-- usage : ${lua_parse conky_show_netdevs}

prev_result = ""

function conky_show_netdevs()
    updates = tonumber(conky_parse("${updates}"))
    interval = 10
    timer = (updates % interval)

    if timer == 0 or prev_result == "" then
        local netdevs_handle = io.popen("ip -j link show up | jq -r '.[] | select(.operstate == \"UP\" and .ifname != \"lo\") | .ifname'")
        local result = ""

        for netdev in netdevs_handle:lines() do
            result = result .. "\nIP (${color1}" .. netdev .. "${color2}): ${alignr}${addr " .. netdev .. "}\n" ..
                     "${color2}Up: ${color2}${upspeed " .. netdev .. "}/s${color1}${alignr}${upspeedgraph " .. netdev .. " 10,170}\n" ..
                     "${color2}Down: ${color2}${downspeed " .. netdev .. "}/s${color1}${alignr}${downspeedgraph " .. netdev .. " 10,170}\n" ..
                     "${color2}Total Down: ${color2}${totaldown " .. netdev .. "}${alignr}Total Up: ${totalup " .. netdev .. "}\n"
        end

        netdevs_handle:close()

        if result ~= "" then
            prev_result = result
        else
            prev_result = "\n"
        end
    end

    return prev_result
end
```

Everything works, except for the `upspeedgraph`s and `downspeedgraph`s, returned in `conky_show_netdevs()` function's output.

Here is an image of the graphs I can see (the small lines in the last section of the image; on the lines where the texts "UP" and "DOWN" are present):

[image: conky window]

---

As far as I could think, I thought this issue was caused due to lua function's contents getting parsed every time conky reloaded, which could cause the graph to reload. So, I tried to increase the update interval of conky to 10 secs. But still, no luck :( .

---

Please tell me why is this happening and how to resolve this issue?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `lua_parse` will run on every update cycle, and so a new
empty graph will be created each time. If you only want to create the
network part of the config once at the start, you can take advantage of the
fact that the `.conkyrc` file is just a lua file, so you can put lua code
in it.

Use this to call a revised function that generates the configuration
string, and concatenate it onto variable `conky.text`. (You used to be able
to access this as a global in lua, but that doesn't seem possible anymore).

So terminate the `.conkyrc` with

```
conky.text = [[
...
${color1}NET: ${hr 2}${color2}
]]
require 'netdevs'
conky.text = conky.text .. conky_show_netdevs()
```

and edit the lua to remove any conky calls, and just return the config:

```lua
-- conky_show_netdevs : template for network
function conky_show_netdevs()
   local netdevs_handle = io.popen(...)
   local result = ""
   for netdev in netdevs_handle:lines() do
      result = result ...
   netdevs_handle:close()
   return result
end
```

Comment: On top of this, I generated a list of all available network devices (whether up or down) and wrapped each one's result in `{$if_up}..${endif}` commands. This meets all of my needs!